# How should I develop old 120 film that has no indication of color, ISO, or process?

Tags: developing, medium-format

My Grandpa found an old 120 film in his Flexaret camera and asked me to develop it. The problem is that on the film is no text and I have no idea about the type (color or b&w?), ISO or what process I should use. He told me that the film is maybe 30 - 35 years old. If anyone can help me I will be grateful.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Interesting... there just *might* be something on the film (from the way the little hands on the first pic are pointed it seems the film is indeed exposed). I never heard of Czechoslovak soldiers in Armenia and Georgia, but at the times of Soviet Union everything was possible. If you are a Czech speaker, which I assume by the accents in your login name, you can try www.temnakomora.cz - you are likely to find more expert answers there than here / and if not, then www.apug.org

Comment: I would have opened the roll (under regular lightning), and while holding the film tight to prevent it from unrolling completely, just rolled out 5-10cm of the backing paper to see if there are any writing on the paper making it easier to identify the film. The hands are pointing in the direction of transport, so this film is definitely rolled to the end and is not a new film.

Answer (score 3):

The film is Black & White. I know this because I was in the photofinishing business for 55 + years. Normally roll film has an adhesive label that one licks and seals on an exposed roll. This one is held tight by medical adhesive tape. Likely this film has never been exposed. Anyway, just look on line for a local shop that does black & white. If you wish to develop this yourself, just use your usual methods. Assume the film to be 100 ISO. Don't expect prize pictures. Likely the film will reveal a high fog level.
Best of Luck

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am very grateful for your advice! My grandpa said that when he was as the Czechoslovakian soldier in Armenia and Georgia, this film stuck in his camera and now he is just curious if there is something on the film or not.

Comment: If you want to be absolutely sure, in a darkened room, unfasten the tape and showily unwind the paper from the role. After a few turns, you will encounter the film interleaved with the paper. If film is taped to paper, the film has never been exposed. If the film is not taped, the film has been run through the camera. An unexposed roll must have film securely fastened to the paper. Be careful doing this exploring. Sit in the darkness for about 15 minutes to dark adapt to check if room is truly dark. After finding film, rewind tightly and and seal with adhesive tape.

Comment: @AlanMarcus I don't doubt that you know this film is B&W or that it is B&W, but would you mind sharing with us what clues you saw in the two images of the film that convinced you of such?

Comment: @ Michael Clark - The red paper backing is familiar -- it is a private label film but I can't remember the brand. It is unlikely that color film would be spooled red. But I have been wrong a zillion times. If it is a color film - what process? Best to develop as black & white. If so processed it can be salvaged by bleaching and re-developing.

Comment: @AlanMarcus Many manufacturers used very similar red backing paper for roll films. If the film is from an old Czechoslovakian camera and the camera has been used in the east block before 1990, the film is most likely from one of the larger east block companies. At least Svema and ORWO used very similar backing paper, but at least ORWO films had more writing on the last part of the backing paper.